# Progress dialog blinking in retrofit

Tags: android-studio

When an activity is opened ,while selecting the item in dropdown according to the postion and fetching the data the progress dialog is continuosly blinking .i cannot do anthing thing in that activity as a further step,would some one please suggest me the solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this issue.This will come due to pagination thing wile calling an API.every time api is called pagination condition is true according to the lastnumber count and the total count.we have to make the condition also false by making lastnumber count less than the total number count.